# Very simple LINQ query, passing in textbox value to the where clause

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I want my LINQ query to count the number of instances a member is present in a table based on what the user enters into a textbox.

As a result, I have the following

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoginDataContext lg = new LoginDataContext();

    int logincheck = (from r in lg.tblOnlineReportingLogins
                      where r.MemberID == tbxMember.Text.ToString()
                      select r).Count();
```

When I debug this, the value appears as 0 when I know this is not the case.

Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: have you established that the text property actually has the expected value? (correct case, no leading/trailing whitspace and such)?

Comment: Hello Rune, yes the value I am entering to test this is exactly the value in the datatable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the `MemberId` property is an integer. So you cannot compare it against a string value. `Text.ToString()` is redundant anyway, since `Text` is already a string.

```
where r.MemberId.ToString() == tbxMember.Text
```

should work.

A cleaner solution would be to parse the `Text` property into an `int` value (together with some validity checking) and do the comparison using `int`s, like

```
int targetId;
if (Int32.TryParse(tbxMember.Text, out targetId)) {
    int logincheck = (from r in lg.tblOnlineReportingLogins
                  where r.MemberID == tbxMember.Text.ToString()
                  select r).Count();
    // ...
} else {
    MessageBox.ShowMessage("Invalid Id");
}
```

**EDIT**: Sorry, perhaps I was too quick, I assumed `MemberId` was an integer. But in this case, your code shouldn't even have compiled. I'm just wondering about the upvotes :-) ...

Comment: The latter should be more efficient.

Comment: That has worked a treat - potentially the MemberID may also be a string however... (Lots of up votes up for grabs : D )  eg. member ID = MM12345 or simply just 123

Comment: i.e. the type is nvarchar

PS: I really appreciate the help, I'm feeling so dense at the moment. I know what I want to do, I just don't know how to go about doing it.

Comment: I would do the following: what gives `lg.tblOnlineReportingLogings.Count()`, what can you see with `from r in lg.tblOnlineReportingLogins select (r => MessageBox.ShowMessage("'"+r.MemberId+"'='"+tbxMember.Text))` and so on (supposing, you've got an winforms app. If not, verify the contents of the table *as seen by your application* in some ASP.NET output or some log file)

Comment: Ok cool - yeah I'll take it one step at a time. Thanks for the advice.